# tiny fonts for IEEEtran not working on biblography

Tags: fontsize, ieeetran

I added `\tiny` before adding `\bibliographystyle`. But it is not changing the font size. Any suggestions for reducing the font size of the reference?

```
\tiny{
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
}
```

Comment: if you trying to set bibliography to smaller then main (where main is pt.10)text just use  \begin{thebibliography}...as i remember it makes it pt.8 or so ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is deliberately prevented. You must understand that the `IEEEtran` class really works as a sort of 'container' for the contents of your paper and effort has been made to have all the formatting already done, so all the papers in the journal/conference proceeding will look the same. So it's not a good idea to alter the formatting, unless you know, what you're doing. But enough of this sermon, of course there is a way around it. `:)` You should try to modify the font size in the *preamble*, like this:

```
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\tiny}
```

Comment: hm when I try this I get a `\bibfont undefined`

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet has been "freshly" tested for one of my IEEE papers. :) Add somewhere in the preamble before `\begin{document}`:

```
\renewcommand{\IEEEbibitemsep}{0pt plus 0.5pt}
\makeatletter
\IEEEtriggercmd{\reset@font\normalfont\fontsize{7.9pt}{8.40pt}\selectfont}
\makeatother
\IEEEtriggeratref{1}
```

Here you can play with the spacing between items (first line), and the overall font size of the bibliography (third line). Works for me!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.